# CloudKit storing and restoring data when testing, app is now released and users are losing their data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, restore, cloudkit

I am using Swift. I can show my code if need be but there is a lot and it may be confusing and unnecessary (if you want to see if please let me know).

So my game needs to save things like high scores and purchases. When I am testing my app with Xcode, high scores get saved and I can delete the app, reinstall, and it pulls from CloudKit successfully. I submitted the application to Apple and they too found that the CloudKit purchase tracking system was working and let it go through to the app store. I told a few friends about my app and wanted them to test it a bit. For some reason though whenever they delete and reinstall the app all their data is lost! It is not performing the same way it does for me on Xcode (or for Apple for that matter).

The really annoying thing is that it takes 3-5 days for any updates I write to make it to the update and I can't even identify the problem yet because here on Xcode it works perfectly.

Does anyone know where the problem might lie? Where I might look in my code or places I could check?

Thanks!

Edit 1: Also a kind of follow up: A friend of mine is abroad and is always on airplane mode. When I check the CKContainerID on airplane mode when testing it finds the user perfectly. For him, however, it thinks that no user is signed in.

Why is all this different in production??

Edit 2: I'm finding some things regarding production cloudkit and development cloudkit? I am totally unfamiliar with this. Secondly I haven't messed around with the CloudKit Dashboard. My code basically tries to pull from the user's CloudKit and if it can't find those records then it will use the saveRecord function to create it.

Edit 3: Have just looked at this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/DeployingYourCloudKitApp/DeployingYourCloudKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH10 and when I have followed those steps to deploy schema I see that the "changes to record types" lists every record I have. Does this mean that there currently are no records for production meaning no one can save anything? Do I  just need to follow all these steps to deploy to development and I'm okay? I'm not too sure what this does so I am hesitant to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! Refer to my 3rd edit. Basically my data holders were all in the development cloud thus when users tried to save/pull their data there wasn't anything in the production cloud for them to save to/pull from. By following that little Apple tutorial and essentially pushing my schema from development to production my users were able to store their data about 10 minutes afterwords!